# Scala - Map of list convert to map

Tags: scala

I have List of map like below.

> List(Map(AAA -> 1111), Map(BBB -> 22222), Map(CCC -> 3333))

I would like to convert like below

> Map( AAA->111, BBB-> 222, CCC->333)

I know it can convert like

```
newmap:map[string, string]
list.foreach( keyValueSet => keyValueSet.foreach( case(key,value) => add on new map)))
```

but want to convert it more scalatic(?) way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `flatten` and `toMap` will do the trick:

```
scala> val listOfMaps = List(Map("AAA" -> 1111), Map("BBB" -> 22222), Map("CCC" -> 3333))
listOfMaps: List[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(AAA -> 1111), Map(BBB -> 22222), Map(CCC -> 3333))

scala> val singleMap = listOfMaps.flatten.toMap
singleMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(AAA -> 1111, BBB -> 22222, CCC -> 3333)
```

Comment: works for me, thanks :)